# Fontello doesn't work after change htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess, url-rewriting, fontello

I'm using [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) which works before I change htaccess

But after I change htaccess like :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^404 404.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ single.php?tg=$3&b=$2&t=$1&jd=$4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^berita/(.+)$ saring.php?f=kategori&v=$1 [L]
```

Icon doesn't show anymore.., for example, icon before < li > tag just show square icon like this :

[image: fontello li]

I though, it because fontello.css is not loaded yet. But, it was not because of it

[image: fontello css]

Please help me..

Comment: Probably URL issue because you rewrote the URLs using htaccess

Comment: @Mr.Alien : Thx for fast response.. I think so, but I am confused how to handle it .. is there any suggestions mr?

Comment: For a quick fix, use an absolute url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the relative link form the css file correct? Does the font open if you load it directly from the browser (good check to see if your htaccess works)?

Comment: I think, I see the real problem now.. when I try to access file .eot, .woff, and .svg in browser, it will be redirected to 404..

Do you know how to exclude those file from mod_rewrite Laurens?

Comment: Done, I just add htaccess and add RewriteEngine off in the folder that contain those file

Comment: I exclude files like this: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg|...etc)?$ [NC]`